# Fields of the model in different apps for Django

Tags: django, django-models

[Screenshot from Order APP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaEcs.png) I am facing a trouble in accessing one variable from an app in different app. 
I have two apps, "Inventory" and "Order". 
In Inventory app, I created different models with some variables. 
In Order App, I need to access the variable Field (QUANTITY) from Inventory app.

Code from Inventory app (in models.py)

```
 --- - - --  - - - - 
  class Items(models.Model):
   name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Quantity=models.IntegerField()
 ----------
```

Code From Order App (in models.py)

```
------
      class NewOrder(models.Model):
          OrderName=models.CharField(max_length=200) 
          Inventory = models.ForeignKey(Items,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
          Total=models.ForeignKey(Items.Quantity,on_delete=models.CASCADE) # This is not working . 
  ------
```

Comment: `myorder.Inventory.Quantity`. But please make your code PEP-8 compliant.

Comment: to access quantity you can use the  foreign key relationship. More about the foreign key relationships in django you can find https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem can you please explain ? :)

Comment: @DimitrisKougioumtzis. I've used that as shown above. 
     def __str__(self):
       return name; # will only show the name of the items. 
Although return str(Quantity) will show the quantity indeed. 

But I need to access each variable of the Items in other apps. I hope I explained well.

Comment: Screenshot is attached from Order APP.
It is showing the name of Item along with Quantity of inventory. But i need to show them in separate columns.

Comment: Add your code for your view and your html table

Comment: Then it will lead to my custom own layout. Will not show up on default layout of Django backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
orders = NewOrder.objects.filter(inventory__quanity)
```

Notice the double underscore. More on how to do this [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

When you create a foreign key field, I would name the field the same thing that it represents. Change **Inventory** to **Items** to reflect the relationship.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Edited code is:
                    Items = models.ForeignKey(Items, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
                 Quantity=NewOrder.objects.filter(Inventory__Quantity)

Now the error is : NewOrder is not defined .

Comment: You have to import the model - ```from app.models import NewOrder```.

Comment: This line of code is in the models.py of Order app where the NewOrder class have been defined. 
Are you suggesting to write this code in models.py of Inventory app?

Comment: Will you post the content of both ```models.py``` files here?